# Addtional configuration when deploying Data Tier Applications?

Tags: sql-server, ssdt

I'm starting a few new database projects and I'm attempting to create them at Data Tier Applications. There are two items I'm not able to find documentation for. I would like to set the db owner to SA and set the initial filesize and growth rate. Even if those items are outside the scope of the app, I would expect that there would some way to specify that at publish time, either in SSDT or SSMS. I can find no documentation either way. Is this the case?

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct way to set/change the ownership as a part of CREATE or ALTER DATABASE statement.

If you want to enforce that, you can do this by adding a post deployment script which calls sp_changedbowner.

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/gertd/changing-database-ownership) article describes that in detail. Similar approach can be applied to set the initial file size and growth Rate as well.

Also, as a note: sp_changedbowner is now depreciated, so it is better to use [ALTER AUTHORIZATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms187359%28v=sql.100%29)

Answer (score 2):

Agree with @Kin on the database owner front, that needs to be done with post-deployment scripts as far as I know.

You can handle the file sizing issue with an SSDT object script so long as you create a filegroup other than `PRIMARY`. This is generally recommended anyway, so why not.

Filegroup script:

```
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
ADD FILEGROUP [USER];
```

File 1:

```
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
ADD FILE
(
    NAME = [USER_File1],
    FILENAME = '$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_USER_File1.ndf',
    SIZE = 1GB,
    FILEGROWTH = 128MB
)
TO FILEGROUP [USER];
```

File 2:

```
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
ADD FILE
(
    NAME = [USER_File2],
    FILENAME = '$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_USER_File2.ndf',
    SIZE = 1GB,
    FILEGROWTH = 128MB
)
TO FILEGROUP [USER]
```